# .NET Application receiving 503 Service Unavailable error when calling web service

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

This is a bit of unusual problem that I'm experiencing, but recently one of the users of a production application started reporting errors in the system. These were traced to a 503 Service Unavailable error when making a call to a web service used by the application.

Now here's the odd part, only the one user is affected by this issue. Other users of the application have not reported any errors. When the user logged on to a different machine that worked for another user, they still received the error.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's going on - but maybe your server does. Ask it, nicely.

Take a look in the event logs, and in fact at the IIS logs. There may have been more 503 errors than you think, and possibly from users who have not reported them. Attempt to correlate event log entries with the IIS entries.

You might also consider running a PerfMon log to collect performance counters for the server. Start small - pick just a few performance counters. If the problem happens and nothing is interesting in the performance counters, then add more.

Finally, consider the possibility that the server may be telling you the truth. Perhaps there are no available connections or threads for some period of time.

Comment: I'm currently going through the logs, but if the issue was due to lack of available connections wouldn't it also affect more users? Or failing at that, not constantly affect the same user?

Comment: Don't assume that all the affected users reported it. That's why I wanted you to look at the logs - to see how many errors IIS reported.

Comment: I couldn't find any errors in the log, so it looks like that route is providing us with limited information. In regards to the users, the application has a limited deployment and is used on a daily basis so I hear about errors right away and nothing has been reported to me outside of this one issue.

Is there anything on the configuration side that would apply to a single user that might cause something like this?

Comment: The other sort of thing that could be per-user is network-related. I've seen oddities with users on particular network segments, for instance. Also, Internet proxy server configuration differs per-user, as does other network configuration. It may be necessary to watch the network when the problem occurs.

Comment: I would have to double check with our network group, but I believe the proxy server does depend upon the user, which would explain why the application didn't work on a system that was known to when they logged into it. However, how would I go about testing this?

Comment: You might have to watch the network while that user tries to use the web service.

Comment: John, thanks for your help with this but once we finally sat down at the users machine we found that we had broken one of the fundamental rules of troubleshooting, namely, don't assume you know how the machine is configured. Turns out that someone the user had gotten the link for the development version of the application which was pointing at a different server for the web service than that of production.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added urlacl for ServiceStack port? In my case, deleting urlacl solved problem for Microsoft Server 2019.